# What is the name of the instrumental theme in Episode 3 of My Hero Academia which starts at 4:52?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

Could any of you please tell me what is the name of the instrumental theme in Episode 3 of My Hero Academia, which starts at 4:52? I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

That song is "Plus Ultra", composed by Yuki Hayashi. [(Disc 1, Track #18 of "Boku no Hero Academia" Original Soundtrack](http://vgmdb.net/album/58868)